# Automatic reminder first working day of the month

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel tool that is used daily by a lot of people - each month they are expected to run a macro to report data to a central point.

Is there a way that I can call a macro such as this as the document is opened?

How would you go about doing this in the Workbook_Open event? Would you make it optional or give users no choice (i.e. auto submit on said day?)

This would potentially help me from chasing people up monthly

As a side note, if I gave users the 'option' - is there a less crude way of reminding them? For example if answer = vbNo Then range("A1") = "1" and then having an if statement within workbook open until they press yes which would set range ("A1") to 0 or similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very much on the right track.

Make a `reference` worksheet in the workbook with the end-of-month dates listed in A1:A12, then place this code in the `Workbook_Open` event.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim dDate as Date

dDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, 0)

With Worksheets("reference")

    Dim rFound As Range
    Set rFound = .Range("A1:A12").Find(dDate, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)

    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then

        If rFound.Offset(, 1) = 0 Then

            Dim ret As Variant
            ret = MsgBox("Would you like to submit data now?", vbYesNo)
            If ret = vbYes Then

                'run macro to submit data
                rFound.Offset(, 1) = 1
                'you may want to set this cell to 1 also if the user submits data manually so it knows for next time

            Else

                'set to zero to check for next time
                rFound.Offset(, 1) = 0

            End If

        End If

    End If

End With

End Sub
```

This is optional for the user, but will repeatedly ask them each time they open the book until they do submit for that month. Then it will wait until next month to ask again.

The problem with making it auto-submit on a given day is that what if the user never opens the workbook on said day?

Comment: Great Response @scott-holtzman - very helpful, no idea why you were inherently at -1 when I saw your response, but I have voted it up and ticked it regardless - thank you for the clarification :)

Comment: @OliEshmade - I suspect its because the way you wrote your question was "out-of-scope" for SO and was primarily asking for opinions and not actual help with code that was not working. I looked past that this time and decided to offer some help. Glad it my intuition was correct.